# How can I generate multiple output files in for loop

Tags: bash, loops, for-loop

I am new to bash so this is a very basic question:
I am trying to use the below written  $for loop to perform a series of commands for several files in a directory, which should end in a new output (f:r.bw) for every single file.
Basically, I have files like `chr1.gz`, `chr2.gz` and so on that should end up as `chr1.bw`, `chr2.bw` ...
The way it is now, it seems to constantly overwrite the same output file and I cannot figure out what the correct syntax is.

```
$ for file in *.gz
do
zcat < $file | grep -v ^track > f:r.temp
wigToBigWig -clip -fixedSummaries -keepAllChromosomes f:r.temp hg19.chrom.sizes f:r.bw
rm f:r.temp
done
```

Thanks for help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of using a fixed filename `f:r.temp`, base your destination name on `$file`:

```
for file in *.gz; do
  zcat <"$file" | grep -v '^track' >"${file%.gz}.temp"
  wigToBigWig -clip -fixedSummaries -keepAllChromosomes \
    "${file%.gz}.temp" hg19.chrom.sizes "${file%.gz}.bw"
  rm -f "${file%.gz}.temp"
done
```

`${file%.gz}` is a [parameter expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073) operation, which trims `.gz` off the end of the name; `${file%.gz}.bw`, thus, trims the `.gz` and adds a `.bw`.

---

Even better, if `wigToBigWig` doesn't need a real (seekable) input file, you can give it a pipeline into the `zcat | grep` process directly and not need any temporary file:

```
for file in *.gz; do
  wigToBigWig -clip -fixedSummaries -keepAllChromosomes \
    <(zcat <"$file" | grep -v '^track') \
    hg19.chrom.sizes \
    "${file%.gz}.bw"
done
```

Comment: Thanks! I tried the upper suggestion and it is working!